# UNLocationNotificationTrigger is not working

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, localnotification

UNLocationNotificationTrigger is not working.

Even ,CLLocationManager didEnterRegion()  is working.

I have added both locationManager.startMonitoring(for:region) and          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

Even I tried by removing locationManager.startUpdatingLocation().But not working

```
func startMonitoring(list:List) {
        if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
            return
        }
        self.list = list
        let region =  self.region(list: list)
        self.locationBasedNotification(list: list, flag: true, region: region as! CLCircularRegion)
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for:region)
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func stopMonitoring(list:List) {
        self.list = list
        for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
            let circularRegion = region as? CLCircularRegion
            if circularRegion?.identifier == list.identifier {
                self.locationBasedNotification(list: list, flag: false, region: circularRegion!)
                locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: circularRegion!)
             //   monitoredRegions.removeValueForKey(region.identifier)
            }
        }
    }


    func locationBasedNotification(list:List,flag:Bool,region:CLCircularRegion) {
        var trigger : UNLocationNotificationTrigger!
        if flag == true {

            self.locationIdentifier = "location"+String(list.seqNo)
            let categoryIdentifier = "locationmyCategory"+String(list.seqNo)
            let textIdentifier = "locationtext"+String(list.seqNo)

            let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.locationIdentifier!, title: "You, have entered \(list.storeName)", options: [])
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryIdentifier, actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

            trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: true)

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent.init()
            content.title = list.storeName
            content.body = "They are \(list.totalItems) in Shopping List"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            content.categoryIdentifier = categoryIdentifier

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: textIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["locationIdentifier"+String(list.seqNo)])
        }
    }
```

please provide me input on this

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes,I have fixed  . When I went to specific location, notification triggered .But through simulator  not working

Comment: Okay many thanks ;) So your code above is working?

Comment: Yes. It is working

Comment: I am trying to work with UNLocationNotificationTrigger for the first time now.
I have a question about your code. How is List defined?